# Approximations and limits for Lambert $W$ of decreasing functions

Tags: lambert-w

I'm aware of the following approximation that approaches the Lambert W Function:
$$
W(f(x))\approx\ln\left(f(x)\right)-\ln\left(\ln(f(x))\right)
$$
However, this approximation fails to capture the Lambert $W$ function if $f(x)$ is a decreasing function. Is there an approximation, potentially in terms of logs (though not necessarily) that approaches the same limit as the product log of a decreasing function? Thanks.

Comment: There are various expansions [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog/06/01/)

Comment: This approximation in fact works well if $f(x)$ tends to infinity as $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: In what range of $X$ do you want to approximate $W(X)$ ?